# Custom baud rate using pyserial

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

How do I set non-standard baud rate on pySerial? According to the documentation it says that pySerial supports non-standard baud rates on certain platform. When I tried configuring pySerial with a non-standard baudrate(12800) it ended up picking a standard one without throwing a warning. How do I check if my platform supports non-standard baudrates?

```
    The parameter baudrate can be one of the standard values: 50, 75, 110, 
134, 150, 200, 300, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600,
115200. These are well supported on all platforms.

    Standard values above 115200, such as: 230400, 460800, 500000, 576000,
921600, 1000000, 1152000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 3000000, 3500000, 4000000
 also work on many platforms and devices.

    Non-standard values are also supported on some platforms (GNU/Linux, MAC 
OSX >= Tiger, Windows). Though, even on these platforms some serial ports may 
reject non-standard values.
```

I am using

```
Linux raspberrypi-zero1 4.4.34+ #930 Wed Nov 23 15:12:30 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom baudrates are set the same way as standard baudrates, with the `baudrate` option. Pyserial will open the port, and set baudrate to the given value, and then Pyserial will read the baudrate back from the serial, to get the actual obtained setting. So if it does not match, then it is likely that the port does not support non-standard baud rates. Here is an example where it works:

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=2345)
>>> ser
Serial<id=0xb73467cc, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=2345, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

Comment: if typing `ser` and under the `baudrate` parameter we see the value we set can we safetly assume that the port can handle that value?

Comment: Yes, that would be most likely. There are so many platforms and hardware out there that it would be difficult to be 100% certain :)

Comment: I am wondering if there is any way to check it in a simple and safe manner 

Answer (score 0):

According to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py`, which is the file used by pyserial in Python3 on Raspberry Pi to open and configure serial ports, if the baud rate you specify is not one of the standard ones, it calls `_set_special_baudrate`. If the platform has not implemented it, the base class throws `NotImplementedError('non-standard baudrates are not supported on this platform')`. So if you're not seeing that error, then the platform (attempts to) supports it.

On Raspberry Pi, the pyserial uses the "Linux" implementation, which means `_set_special_baudrate` is defined, and attempts to set the custom baud rate using ioctl TCSETS2 calls. If this fails, it's supposed to raise `ValueError('Failed to set custom baud rate ({}): {}'.format(baudrate, e))`.

So in summary, if you specify your custom baud rate in the normal way, PySerial should dutifully apply it and raise an exception if it fails. If it doesn't, it should be safe to assume it has worked, but the Linux serial driver is funky so caveat emptor. Note that checking the value of baudrate is not a reliable way to confirm success - it simply contains the request baudrate you supply.